# Updating a listbox item value

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox and each item is made up of an object called Part which consists of 2 strings `Part.PartNo` & `Part.Filename`.  I want to do something like this:

```
((Part)drawingList.Items[activeItem]).Filename = "My new value";
```

But I'm getting the error that it can't be assigned to because it is read only.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: is it Part.FileName property that is read only?

Comment: Please add Part class code to your question Paul.

Comment: My crystal ball whispered: "Part is a struct, not a class.  The actual error message is *Cannot modify the result of a unboxing conversion*".  It's not wrong often, make it a class.

Comment: alexm had it....ugh, that's embarrassing hahahahaha.  I had a get{}but no set{} for Part.Filename!

Answer (score 0):

Listbox Items are strings (Winforms) so you'll have to parse the string and extract the two values. If there is a space separating them you'll have to do a...

```
string[] tokens = listbox.items[i].split(new char[] {' '});
Part p = new Part() {partno = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]), filename = "my new value"};
```